# Z3Py: getting the function corresponding to each operator e.g. '*', '==', '-'

Tags: python, z3, sympy, z3py

I want to generate equations/inequalities in `Z3Py` automatically using an algorithm I'm developing. To achieve this, I need to use operators such as  `==`, `+`, `*` as functions.

For example in `Sympy`, I can add two symbols as follows

```
import sympy as sp
sp.Add(x, y)
```

which results in `x + y`.

Can I do the same in `Z3Py`?

For computation speed, I believe it's not a good idea to convert from or to a string representation of the expression.

Comment: maybe take a look at the [`operator` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.add).

Comment: When I had played with z3py in the past, it was helpful for me to just read the [source code](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/tree/master/src/api/python) to see what was there. It isn't documented very well, but the actual Python wrapper source is relatively small compared to Z3 itself, which is written in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find any documentation (and I assume you can't either) for direct support by z3py, however all implicit operations in python have callable functions in the `operator` module:

```
import operator

x,y = Ints("x y")

a = operator.add(x,y)
```

if you want to map the functions to their symbols you can use a dict:

```
ops = {"+":operator.add, "*":operator.mul} #etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
import z3

x, y = z3.Ints('x y')
print z3.ExprRef.__eq__(x, y)
```

Comment: how would you do this for something like `3<= x <= 7`?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen `3 <= x <= 7` isn't an operator in Python. Python automatically chains relational operators, but it does it in such a way that programs like Z3 and SymPy can't represent them symbolically. You can see http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#greaterthan for some discussion on this. To represent that, you have to use `And(3 <= x, x <= 7)` (using whatever And is called in Z3, probably `(3 <= x) & (x <= 7)` works as well, but you have to be careful about the precedence).